# How can i make a image to fit

Tags: html, css, image

Can someone help me please with my problem. I dont know very good about html i have found some code to solve it but i cant use them i dont know where exactly to form them.
I want to make the imcage fit to each users resolution and dont appears right and down of their screen white boxes. I want to fit 100% in window. I hope you understand what  i mean.
My code is this.

```
<style>
<!--
BODY {background-image: url(bg_body.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
-->
</style>
```

i hope you can help me thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm.. Where is the code?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<img src='whatever.png' style='width: 100%; height: 100%' />
```

This will make the image fill its parent container.

Comment: <style>
<!--
BODY {background-image: url(bg_body.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
-->
</style> this is my code. Can you aply george please to this

Comment: @giogram: Change it to: `<style> <!-- body { margin: 0px; } --> </style>` and stick `<img src='whatever' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' />` where you want the image to go. (Don't forget to replace `whatever` with the filename of the image.)

Comment: do you have msn or skype or smth to speak live....i want to ask some think more if you can tell me

Comment: If you have something more to ask, please post another question. Then copy and paste the link here.